# How to get current state of expanded/collapsed groups?

Tags: angular-slickgrid

I'm unable to capture current state of a tree data grid  which includes capturing the expanded & collapsed groups.

I am trying to capture the expanded groups in slickgrid so as to retain their expanded state after I have refreshed the grid. I am trying to capture the grouping keys of all groups that have been expanded but I have been unable to do so.

```
this.gridDataViewObj.onGroupExpanded.subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: in Angular-Slickgrid discussion, you wrote that it's a Tree Data grid but in this question here, you don't mention that at all, is that the case? Because if it's the case, then the events are totally different and there is not enough details to help with your question, please provide more details